# Android : onTouchEvent gives weird coordinates on clicking left corner

Tags: android, touch-event

I am implementing `onTouch` event and getting x an y coordinates on clicking

```
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();
```

I am clicking the left top corner of the screen in emulator, but getting coordinates as `(0,25)` instead of `(0,0)`.

I tried this in multiple versions of Android but the result is same.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: don't you receive a coordinate that is below the status bar?

Comment: Nopes. I have put a log and the coordinates that i get clicking on extreme left corner is 0,25 but surely not 0,0

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is something to do with Emulator. On devices it is working fine.
On Emulator with do scaling that's why it is not giving correct coordinates.